# Require a java program to create method templates

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains the list of all public method names. I require a Java program which reads each method name from the text file and create a method(template) for each public method name.
Say,
My text file contains, 3 methods

```
public static void A()
public static void B()
public static void C()
```

I need a output like this.

```
public class class_name
{
 public void A_test()
 {
   System.out.println("Method A");
 }

 public void B_test()
 {
   System.out.println("Method B");
 }
 public void C_test()
 {
   System.out.println("Method C");
 }
}
```

Kindly give your suggestions.

Comment: Please try something and come back with specific questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like you are asking other people to write code for you. This is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Just a tip: https://github.com/forge/roaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example above the code below will generate a similar output. Note there is no package. **NOTE** As your example the generator strips `static`

```
public class ClassBuilder
{

  public static String buildClass(String className,ArrayList<String> methods)
  {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("public class %s \n{", className)).append("\n");
    for (String method: methods)
    {
      stringBuilder.append(String.format("    %s \n    {", method.trim().replace("static ","").replace("()","_test()"))).append("\n    }\n\n");      
    }
    stringBuilder.append("}");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try
    {
      scanner = new Scanner(new File("d:\\testFile.txt"));

      ArrayList<String> methods = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (scanner.hasNext())
      {
        methods.add(scanner.nextLine());
      }
      scanner.close();

      String javaClass = buildClass("className", methods);

      System.out.println(javaClass);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

output

```
public class className 
{
    public void A_test() 
    {
    }

    public void B_test() 
    {
    }

    public void C_test() 
    {
    }

}
```